# Laravel: Pass an array from controller, to mail::to

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In my project after someone fill a pricequote I want to send an email for him/her. In the controller I made an array what I want to pass to the mailable, to show on the email.

Where I'm now:

```
$params = array(
        'name' => $name, //user's data
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'data' => $data, //other stuffs in the form 
);

Mail::to($email)
    ->send(new pricequote($params));
```

And after that how to pass from the mailable class to the template?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add: 5.4

Comment: Updated my answer for L5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use;

**namespace App\Mail;**

```
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.contacts')
        ->with(['data' => $this->data]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the pricequote is  the mailable class, then your pricequote mailable class should look like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class pricequote extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The data for the email instance.
     *
     * @var data
     */
    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('yourview')
                    ->with(['data' => $this->data]);
    }
}
```

Then in your controllers you can send the email like this:

```
Mail::to("mail@email.com")->send(new pricequote($data));
```

**Laravel 5.1**:

You can choose the view you want to send as email like this:

```
$params = array(
    'name' => $name, //user's data
    'email' => $email,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'data' => $data, //other stuffs in the form 
); 

Mail::send('view', $params, function($m){

    $m->to($this->argument('to_email'));

});
```

The first argument is the view and second the data you want to have access on the view.